# Long table : I am facing problem here with 2 errors: misplaced no align and misplaced omit. Please tell me how to fix these?

Tags: longtable

```
\begin{longtable}{p{8cm} | p{3.5 cm} | p{2cm}}

\caption{Concerns}
\label{tab}
\hline
\textbf{Representative Quotes}
 & \textbf{Points}
 & \textbf{thoughts}
 \\
 \hline
```

Comment: you need `\\ ` after the label, before the `\hline`

Comment: You’re missing ``\\`` before the first `\hline`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked

Comment: The issue has been solved in the comments and answers won’t be beneficial to future readers